# C#: How to reduce following code

Tags: c#

I want to perform same process as function is performing now, But I want more compact function.

Can any one please help me to reduce this code...?

```
private void UpdateView(bool IsUpdateViewRequired)
{
        try
        {
            if (IsUpdateViewRequired == true)
            {
                this.Height = 210;
                labelStatus.Text = string.Empty;
                progressBar.Value = 0;
                buttonCancel.Visible = true;
                buttonStart.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Height = 165;
                buttonCancel.Visible = false;
                buttonStart.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `try/catch`.

Comment: Shorter code doesn't always mean better code. Just leave it as it is in this case.

Answer (score 6):

```
private void UpdateView(bool IsUpdateViewRequired)
{
    if (IsUpdateViewRequired) progressBar.Value = (labelStatus.Text = string.Empty).Length;
    this.Height = (buttonStart.Visible = !(buttonCancel.Visible = IsUpdateViewRequired)) ? 165 : 210;
}
```

Enjoy the shortness;) Sorry it this is not readable.

Comment: Cool, dude. Now I only need my cocktail for full enjoyment.

Answer (score 3):

you could reduce the code to the below code (i dont think this would make any difference as your statements are just simple commands)

```
private void UpdateView(bool IsUpdateViewRequired)
{

            if (IsUpdateViewRequired == true)
            {
                this.Height = 210;
                labelStatus.Text = string.Empty;
                progressBar.Value = 0;

            }
            else
            {
                this.Height = 165;
            }
            buttonCancel.Visible = IsUpdateViewRequired;
            buttonStart.Visible = !IsUpdateViewRequired;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't need `try/catch`. You also don't need `== true`. `this.` is also redundant. Moreover you ca eliminate some of `if` statement:

```
 private void UpdateView(bool IsUpdateViewRequired)
 {
            Height =IsUpdateViewRequired? 210:165;
            buttonCancel.Visible = IsUpdateViewRequired;
            buttonStart.Visible = !IsUpdateViewRequired;
            if (IsUpdateViewRequired)
            {
               labelStatus.Text = string.Empty;
               progressBar.Value = 0;
            }            
}
```

Comment: I guess you can collapse the 2 Visible statements into a single one

Comment: he could need try/catch if buttonCancel, buttonStart could not exist at the function call. But this should be solved with better code

Comment: It is shorter, but I would much prefer the original version posted by OP. I know, I know, give 'em what they wanted :)